This expression is not callable
Below should work, I think code is correct for functionality, but I get this error in my `component that I do not know how to fix, please help?
This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string | ((sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void)' are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures.ts(2349) const open: string | ((sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void)
Hook:
export default function useOpen() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState("closed");
  const open = (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) =>
    setIsOpened(status ? sectionName : "closed");
  return [isOpened, open];
}

Component:
export default function Opendiv() {
  const [ isOpened, open ] = useOpen();
 return (
    <div>
     <button type="button" onClick={() => open(item.chapter)} className=""></button>
     {isOpened === item.chapter && (
     <div className="transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out">Opened div, opened div, opened div</div>  
     )}
     </div>);}


When returning an array typescript infers its type such that all elements could be of all the types contained in the array. In your case defining a tuple as returntype of your hook should do the trick: function useOpen(): [string, (sectionName: ...) => void]

What are you trying to achieve with sectionName ?

@0stone0 ... is meant as an ellipsis.

Not sure what you mean by that, don't see it in your code. But if you want just 1 section to be openend, just use a boolean and not strings like 'closed'

@0stone0 Oh, I thought your previous comment was related to my first comment. Then only FunDevGirl can answer that.

@0stone0 - I have multiple sections all with the same item.chapter with each chapter being different ofcourse. I want one chapter to open when clicking the corresponding button, and not all chapters.

@Palladium02 - sorry I do not understand so good. Can you please elabortate please?

Your return [isOpened, setIsOpened] which is of type (string | ((sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void))[]. That is due to the fact that you did not specify a more specific return type, therefore typescript looks at the type of the elements in the array, builds a union of them and infers the arrays type as array of said union. But you know that your array only has two elements making it a "tuple". So you can use [string, (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void] as returntype for useOpen so typescript knows the types when destructuring the array.

If above comment is enough of an explanation I will make it an answer.

@Palladium02 - yes please thank you. I accept answer if you can post with full code for hook that it must be.

Your current implementation of useOpen does not specify a returntype. Therefore Typescript tries to infer the return type based on the returned value(s). In this case of arrays Typescript builds a union type of all types that can be found in the array. In your case string and (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void. When destructing the array the type of the destructured elements will become said union string | (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void. As you know that the length of the returned array will always be two you can specify the returntype of useOpen as a tuple type: [string, ((sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void)]. So the code for useOpen will be:
export default function useOpen(): [string, (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) => void] {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState("closed");
  const open = (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>, status: any) =>
    setIsOpened(status ? sectionName : "closed");
  return [isOpened, open];
}


now new error in component: An argument for 'status' was not provided. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Well your open function expects two arguments, so you should provided that or mark the status argument as optional. (..., status?: any) => void. This change would need to happen in the useOpen signature and the open definition. Choose based on your need.

thank you fast reply. I added second argument in component but now button not toggle anymore. Make status argument optional dont understand. Will it make toggle still? Is new study for me, so if possible to show with code then I learn?

What is status meant to be doing? Are you maybe able to provide a e.g Stackblitz with the code so one can take look at the whole picture and tinker with it?
